# Writing a method that accepts an integer parameter that returns how many times the number can divided by 2

Tags: java, algorithm

I think the title itself is pretty much self explanatory.

for example, if I put in 128, it should print 7.

If I put in a odd number, it should print 0.

My code is

```
public static int divideBy2 (int number){ 

      int count=0;

      while (number%2==0){


         count++;
      }
      return count;
}
```

I do understand why it doesn't work, but I can't think of anything else.

I'm a beginner, and I'm supposed to use the while loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

(This is not a duplicate. That post is about how many times 2 fit in the number, but my question is about dividing the number repeatedly by 2. )

Comment: you need to then divided again by two dont you think?

Comment: you forgot to change the value of number after `count++;` -> `number = number/2`

Comment: What if `number` can be divided by 2 unlimited times and never produce an odd number?

Comment: Please learn to use **debugger**.  Use the appropriate help section of your IDE.

Comment: @khelwood like what ?

Comment: I did use debuger, but couldn't find a way to fix it :(

Comment: @azro Like zero.

Comment: [For geeks: Count trailing zero bits using lookup table](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-trailing-zero-bits-using-lookup-table/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if is divisible, you need to then divided again by two dont you think?

```
while (number%2==0) {
     number /=2;    
     count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, after testing if the number is divisible by two, you actually have to do the division.

Warning!  If given the number 0, you have an infinite loop!  You should protect against that.

Fun fact: it is possible to solve the problem without division, using [Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(number)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros(int)).